# PHP Curl script generating duplicate requests

Tags: php, http, curl, http-post

I have a PHP Curl based function that is used for various requests in an application. The function is normally used to communicate/trigger requests on other servers on same machine (localhost). The function is below: -

```
/**
 * @desc If a curl_multi handle is passed, a new curl 
 * instance is added to the handle and the curl id is returned as string.
 * @param string $theServer
 * @param string $thePath
 * @param number $thePort
 * @param curl_multi $mcHandle
 * @return string|curl_handle
 */
function sendPOSTtoURL($theServer, $thePath, $theData, 
                        $thePort = 80, $mcHandle = null) {
    global $bDebug; $theResult = "";    //$bDebug = true;
    $cPost = curl_init();
    if ($cPost !== false)   {
        curl_setopt($cPost, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$theServer.$thePath);
        if ($thePort != 80) curl_setopt($cPost, CURLOPT_PORT, $thePort);    
            // Set port if different from 80
        curl_setopt($cPost, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($cPost, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
        curl_setopt($cPost, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt ($cPost, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt ($cPost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $theData);
        curl_setopt ($cPost, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $returndata = curl_exec ($cPost);
        if ($mcHandle == null)  {
            if (! $theResult = curl_exec($cPost))   {
                if (curl_errno($cPost) > 0) {   
                                $theResult = CURL_ERROR;    
                                if ($bDebug)    
                                      $theResult .= fcURLError($cPost); 
                            }
                else    {
                                $theResult = CURL_NOERR_NOINFO; 
                                if ($bDebug)
                                      $theResult .= fcURLError($cPost); 
                            }
            }
            curl_close($cPost);
            return $theResult;
        }   else    {
            curl_multi_add_handle($mcHandle, $cPost);
            return $cPost;
        }
    }   else    return CURL_INIT_FAIL;
}
```

I wont go into complexities, but it is designed to return text if it is a single request or a curl handle is appended if a multi_curl handle is passed.

The issue is, when I request it to do a task on a remote server, it does a double request. We have a setup where the requesting server is connected to remote server via VPN and can do a requests to external Internet through it. I thought the target server was running it twice so I made a call (for doing an email) from the calling server as follows: -

```
    $aEmail = array("email_address" => $sEmailAddress, 
                    "email_subject" => $sEmailSubject, 
                    "email_body" => $sEmailBody);
    echo sendPOSTtoURL("<REMOTE IP HERE", 
                       "/emailService/doMail.php?rand=".mt_rand(), 
                       $aEmail);
```

the call to mt_rand generates a random number so I can identify each request. This is what I got at the remote server: -

```
<CALLING IP> - - [15/Jun/2011:20:39:57 +0500] "POST /emailService/doMail.php?rand=1551627310 HTTP/1.1" 200 1060 "-" "-"
<CALLING IP> - - [15/Jun/2011:20:40:01 +0500] "POST /emailService/doMail.php?rand=1551627310 HTTP/1.1" 200 1060 "-" "-"
```

As you can see, the same request came in twice. and what do you think happens? right, 2 emails to the target! I cant (due to managerial [S@#$] reasons) develop logic to handle this on the Remote server.

Comment: is there any authentication?  HTTP Basic auth will respond with a 401 and an authentication realm to the initial request, then when the request is authenticated the whole thing is sent.  This can look like 2 requests on the server end, and depending on how it handles auth may actually hit the application itself.

Comment: There is no authentication. Like I said, 2 emails are generated. The logs also indicate HTTP Response 200 was returned twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have double call curl_exec()

```
$returndata = curl_exec ($cPost);
    if ($mcHandle == null)  {
        if (! $theResult = curl_exec($cPost))   {
```

I think the parameter $mcHandle is null always.

Comment: Total Blindness on my part...! Mega thanks!
However, the $mcHandle is not always null.
Like I said, we use a mechanism whereby we create a curl_multi handle on the outside and call this function in a loop with that handle passed. It is null when NOT passed.

Again, Mega thanks!